# Completing transaction in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, postgresql

I have got follow code:

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(db_from, fields, where_clause="objectid < 11111"):
    value_from = list(row)
    for rowto in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(db_to, fields, where_clause="uid = '" + str(row[0]) + "'"):
        value_to = list(rowto)
        if(set(value_from) == set(value_to)): # data is same
            same +=1
            print "data is same"
        else:
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(db_to, fields, where_clause="uid = '" + str(row[0]) + "'") as cursor:
                for x in cursor:
                    cursor.updateRow(value_from)
                    updated +=1
                    print "data update"
    else:
        to_cursor.insertRow(value_from)
        print "Inserted"

print "Same Data: ", str(same)
print "Updated Data: ", str(updated)
```

I am getting next error:

```
data update
data update
data update
data update
data update
Inserted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\code\Python\work\dbsync.py", line 69, in <module>
    for x in cursor:
RuntimeError: workspace already in transaction mode
```

Where I should to close transaction? Am I right understand that issue is rise when I do insert when transaction (cursor?) of update is still active?

I am using [ArсPy](http://desktop.arcgis.com/ru/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After  updated +=1 use del row and del cursor

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(db_from, fields, where_clause="objectid < 11111"):
    value_from = list(row)
    for rowto in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(db_to, fields, where_clause="uid = '" + str(row[0]) + "'"):
        value_to = list(rowto)
        if(set(value_from) == set(value_to)): # data is same
            same +=1
            print "data is same"
        else:
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(db_to, fields, where_clause="uid = '" + str(row[0]) + "'") as cursor:
                for x in cursor:
                    cursor.updateRow(value_from)
                    updated +=1
            del x
            del cursor


                    print "data update"
    else:
        to_cursor.insertRow(value_from)
        print "Inserted"

print "Same Data: ", str(same)
print "Updated Data: ", str(updated)
```

Comment: wetland, could you explain why? Should I do delete cursor after every insert operation?

Comment: After any update you should delete row and cursor to end the transaction and unlock the feature class

Comment: do not helped :( I also tried variant with `del x` that tabbed to right (it's look mistake in your code)

Comment: I edited my code.  I had a syntax error

Comment: wetland, do you sure that `del x` in your code is on right level?
Do I need remove insert cursor? See that insert inside in global `for` loop.

Comment: When you use updatecursor or insertcursor you should use del . see :http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm   and  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm

Comment: To get it work I need add creating and removing cursor in `insert` block. is it's correct co create and remove cursor every request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49102/discussion-between-wetland-and-user1432751).

Comment: Had this error using <InsertCursor instance>.insertRow in a loop adding data to a geodatabase table. Adding del <InsertCursor instance> resolved it (ArcPro 2.9). No need to delete row tuple in insertRow, it is just a tuple...